# Converting char array to atoi is failing

Tags: c, arrays, atoi

I've checked other posts related to this subject and have used the `atoi` function to convert a string, but the value is always 0.

Here are the values stored in `hold4`:

```
char hold4[4] = { "0", "." , "1", "5", "\0");
```

I then attempt to convert to an `int` and I get

```
int hm = atoi(hold4);
```

`hm` prints out as:

```
hm = 0
```

I expect `hm` to be 0.15, as that's the value in `hold4`.  I want to use this value for subsequent math operations.

Here is my code:

```
int x = 0;
int pixel = 0;  
char hold[10];
char hold4[4];  

for(x=0; x < linesCount; x++)
{
    fscanf(model, "%c", &hold[x]);
    if(hold[x] == '\0' || hold[x] == '\r' || hold[x] == '\n')
    {
        hold4[0] = hold[x-4]; 
        hold4[1] = hold[x-3]; 
        hold4[2] = hold[x-2]; 
        hold4[3] = hold[x-1];
        hold4[4] = '\0'; 
    //  printf("new line: break\n");
    }
    //printf("pixel: %c\n", hold[x]);
}

int hm = atoi(hold4);

printf("\nhold4: %d\n", hm);
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: Did you not notice you were putting 5 values in an array declared to hold only 4?

Comment: Your code should generate massive compiler warnings for converting a pointer to `char`. You try to store `char *` into your a `char` with the initialiser! Compiler warnings/errors are not just for fun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the whole point of integer. Integer is a whole number (1, 2, 3, 4...) and can't have decimal points. What you are looking for is float/double.

[Try with this: atof()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atof.htm)

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly.  In the meantime I went through the trouble of taking just the 1 and 5 converting that to atoi then taking that number and dividing it by 100 to make a .15 float number.  But atof just does exactly what i wanted.  thanks

Comment: I'm glad I helped. Just accept my or Michaels answer so the question gets answered for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

The `atoi` function converts an "array of chars" to an "integer", hence the name: (a)rray (to) (i)nt.

Your array of chars has decimal places, but `atoi` will only convert characters in the range 0-9; it will not return a float value.

Note that your variable `hm` is explicitly an `int` type, and you're printing the value with `%d`, also explicitly `int`.  You've already done everything needed to ensure that the only possibility is an `int` value.

Comment: Thank you, got it!

Answer (score 0):

```
char hold4[5] = { '0', '.' , '1', '5', '\0'};
double a = atof(hold4);
printf("%f",a);
```

try this